# Azure Queue implementation vs other Azure solutions

Tags: azure, queue, system-design

I have to implement a ticketing system and I thought about multiple approaches, and one of them involves a queuing system between sql data and the ticketing app.
Do you agree with this choice?
How would you implement this?
Have you got other ideas? I know that Azure offers a lot of services and I am just at the beginning!

Thanks,
Alfie

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to provide any real architecture guidance given the limited information you've provided, but here are some links that might help you make more informed decisions.

[Azure Architecture Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/) contains a wealth of information about how to architect azure solutions including examples and best practices.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted) comparing two of the popular queuing services available in Azure contains a lot of great information and asks a lot of questions that will help you think about the problem you are trying to solve.

If you add more specifics to your question we can provide more help.